# Control over the number of rows and columns displayed when printing a pandas dataframe in the terminal

Tags: python, pandas

We are struggling to get proper control of the number of columns and rows printed when we print(dataframe). It is super opaque and seems to be based on some mystery terminal size settings.

I am setting:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 400) # or other number has no effect
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 400) # or other number has no effect
```

But the output is still being constrained by something. Perhaps the size of the terminal?

```
           hash                                         email        date                                            subject
0     65319af6e                        jbrockmendel@gmail.com  2020-11-28       REF-IntervalIndex._assert_can_do_setop-38112
1     0bf58d8a9                     simonjayhawkins@gmail.com  2020-11-28   DOC-add-contibutors-to-1.2.0-release-notes-38132
...         ...                                           ...         ...                                                ...
3729  7ecd9af7c                                  kaiqi@kth.se  2020-01-01         CLN-Clean-test-moments-for-expanding-30566
3730  bd78b3206                                  kaiqi@kth.se  2020-01-01  CLN-Clean-_test_moments_consistency-in-common....
```

If I set the max_columns and max_rows to None then the output is completely unconstrained - also undesirable for large datasets.

We are primarily using VScode on ubuntu. Can anyone explain how this works?

Ta, Andrew

Mods: Before marking this question as duplicate - please note, I have checked over lots of similar questions and have not found any answer which actually answers this question. Most of the answers are quite old and do not deal with rows at all or are answers intended for Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `iloc` property to select the size of the dataframe to print.Eg.,

```
print(df.iloc[: no_of_row_to_display , : no_of_col_to_display ] )
```

such as `print(df.iloc[:2,:4])` will print 2 rows and 4 columns.

Here you have one advantage that you can select any rows or column to print by entering the start and end of those row and colums.

Comment: This is great info! I would like to understand how to effect the default behaviour however.

Answer (score 0):

From [Pandas' docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html): `pd.options.display.max_rows = 999`, for example. there is also `max_columns` settings too.

Comment: These setting don't work - I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: You also need to set the `min_rows` and `min_columns` parameters. When you exceed the max values, dataframe is truncated according to the min values. You should [read the docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options)..

Answer (score 0):

The `set_option` seems to work fine in your case. Setting a number will truncate the df when exceeding it while setting it to **`None`** should work in any case.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```